# Cointegration among many Time Series In R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the following code in R to get the P-value via ADF-Test between two Time Series : TS1 and TS2:

```
 m <- lm(TS1 ~ TS2 + 0)
 beta <- coef(m)[1]
 sprd <- TS1 - beta*TS2
 ht <- adf.test(sprd, alternative='stationary', k=0)
 pval <- as.numeric(ht$p.value)
```

If I want to get P-value for ADF for one or two more Time Series (i.e: TS1,TS2 and TS3 or TS1,TS2,TS3 and TS4), what would be the proper syntax considering the above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put your actual code into a *function*. You could use **combn**() to determine the pairs of series. After that loop for all the pairs, using paste to make the regression model, that would be passed to your function as a parameter, you will need to store the p-value into a vector or data.frame, for all the pairs .  Good luck!!

> t(combn(c("TS1","TS2","TS3","TS4"),2))

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer:

```
m <- lm(pair1 ~ pair2 + pair3)
beta1 <- coef(m)[1]
beta2 <- coef(m)[2]
sprd <- pair1 - beta1*pair2 - beta2*pair3
ht <- adf.test(sprd, alternative='stationary', k=0)
```